# mailx cannot send mail through gmail any more?

Tags: mailx

```
mailx -v -r "${USER}@gmail.com" -s "This is the subject" -S smtp="smtps://smtp.gmail.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="${USER}@gmail.com"  ${USER}@gmail.com
```

give out error like this:

```
could not initiate SSL/TLS connection: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

The following:

```
mailx -v -r "${USER}@gmail.com" -s "This is the subject" -S smtp="smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="${USER}@gmail.com"  ${USER}@gmail.com
```

gives:

smtp-server:

```
530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/...
```

What can I do about this?

**update1:**

add `-S ssl-method="tls1"` it gives out the same error. My mailx version is 12.5 6/20/10. Kind of old, but it still supports tls1.

Comment: Your `mailx` seems to use SSLv2/v3, which have been deprecated for security reasons. You'll have to find a version of `mail`, `mailx` or `sendmail` that supports TLSv1. (Perhaps your current one already does and you just need to configure something to enable it.)

Comment: @n.st Thanks. But it still does not work. Please see the update. Anyone tried tls1.2?